Link Field Email with Subject and Body
The Link Field in Craft 5 is a good improvement, but I can't find a way to populate the link with a pre-filled Subject and Body to the email.

In a mailto link, you can enter default values for most fields using URL parameters. Here's an example:
mailto:me@example.com&subject=Foo&body=Bar

This link will open the visitor's e-mail program and set the subject and body fields to Foo and Bar, respectively. You can enter those parameters directly in the Link field when the E-Mail type is selected. Spaces are replaced by + signs after saving, as some characters need to be encoded/escaped in a URL parameter.
If you don't like the user experience of this solution, you can also create additional plain text fields next to the Link field for authors to enter a default subject and body without having to remember any syntax. Then assemble the link in your template from those fields.
See MDN for more details on E-Mail links.
